# Program is over-writing my old data instead of put new data in new row

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, apache-poi

I have created program using Selenium webdriver and JAVA. I am getting data from website and putting in excel. I am writing data like put 10 values then change xpath and put again new 10 values. But my program is overriding old 10 values when I am trying to put new values.So in excel I got 10 values only instead of 20.

Code is :

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;  
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class Retrieve {

    public static WebDriver driver;
    public static int rowcount=0;
    public static int cellcount=0;
    public static String data[] = new String[10];

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        openurl();
        write_data();
    }

    public static void openurl() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "E:\\Selenium-Webdriver\\Chrome_Driver\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();

        driver.get(URL);

        data[0] = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='wpv-view-layout-34546-CPID79']/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/a/b")).getText();
        data[1] = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='wpv-view-layout-34546-CPID79']/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/a/b")).getText();
        data[2] = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='wpv-view-layout-34546-CPID79']/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/a/b")).getText();
        data[3] = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='wpv-view-layout-34546-CPID79']/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[2]/a/b")).getText();
        data[4] = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='wpv-view-layout-34546-CPID79']/table/tbody/tr[5]/td[2]/a/b")).getText();
        data[5] = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='wpv-view-layout-34546-CPID79']/table/tbody/tr[6]/td[2]/a/b")).getText();
        data[6] = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='wpv-view-layout-34546-CPID79']/table/tbody/tr[7]/td[2]/a/b")).getText();
        data[7] = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='wpv-view-layout-34546-CPID79']/table/tbody/tr[8]/td[2]/a/b")).getText();
        data[8] = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='wpv-view-layout-34546-CPID79']/table/tbody/tr[9]/td[2]/a/b")).getText();
        data[9] = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='wpv-view-layout-34546-CPID79']/table/tbody/tr[10]/td[2]/a/b")).getText();
    }


    public static void write_data() throws IOException {
        File file = new File("C:\\Users\\Rahul\\Documents\\Practice.xls");
        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
        Workbook MyWorkbook = null;
        MyWorkbook = new HSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
        Sheet sheet = MyWorkbook.getSheet("sheet1");
        Row row = sheet.getRow(0);
        try{
            int lendgth = data.length;
            for(int i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
                Row newrow = sheet.createRow(rowcount+1);
                Cell cell = newrow.createCell(cellcount);
                if(!data[i].equals("") || data[i].equals(null)) {
                    if(row.equals(null)){
                        newrow.createCell(rowcount);
                        cell.setCellValue(data[i]);
                        rowcount++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }catch(Exception E) {
            E.printStackTrace();
        }

        inputStream.close();
        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        MyWorkbook.write(outputStream);
        outputStream.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the part where you change the xpath, get 10 additional data and and try to write them in the same file?

Comment: I am just replacing given 10 xpaths every time manually and then run program again so it gets new 10 values.

Comment: Well, you always start from row 0 of sheet1. Of course you'll be overwriting the data.

Comment: Yes I want to know that how can I tell to webdriver that if 10 rows are filled with data then start to write on 11th row for new data.

Comment: This has nothing to do with WebDriver. It's the part that you manipulate with Apache POI. So change that to find the first empty row.

Comment: ok let me try in that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are writing the data, try to find the last row in excel sheet and provide that row number(mat be increment if required) instead of always giving row 0 (Row row = sheet.getRow(0);)

thanks